# Can't change my Google profile name

Tags: gmail, google-account, email

My Google name was "The Free Hugs Guy" for a while, and then it got changed to "donut DONUT," and I couldn't change it for three months, so I was like, "Okay, I won't post anything on YouTube or anything for three months, whatever." And then three months passed and I was like, "Hey, I need to change my name back." And then when I made my first name, "The Free Hugs Guy," and had no last name, it was all like, "Something went wrong. Please try again later." So I tried again an hour later, and it didn't work. I tried making my first name, "The Free," and my last name was, "Hugs Guy." That also "went wrong." So the next day I tried again. Same thing. The next week, I tried again. Same thing. Five more times at different times on different days, it was the same thing. What gives? Will I ever be able to get my name back, or am I just screwed? And I mean I don't want to get a reply saying no, but I'd rather that than have a reply saying maybe if the answer is actually no. So should I just make a new Google account? Or should I just keep trying to change this one? And while I'm asking this, I know for a fact that this isn't just a problem all across Google that's lasted this long, so why the heck does it take two weeks for me to change my name once I'm supposed to be allowed to?

Answer (score 0):

Google+ is going away very soon but you still can use this method for now.

Login to your Google+ account, open profile section from the Google+ menu or click here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/me and click to your name at the cover photo to edit your name.

Be aware of the Google+ profile name policy that You can change the name only 3 times in 2 years.

Another thing, after making the change, clear cache in your browser and then look for any changes. If it didn't work, then check your profile details at Google Accounts here https://www.google.com/settings/account?ref=home

Sometimes it is a problem with the browser, make sure you have enabled JavaScript and when you are on the Google+ profile page, let the page load completely and then click for the modal box to show up.

It would be best to use the latest, updated version of Google Chrome https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/